# Collapse of Serre spectral sequence in the presence of a cross-section

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences, fibration

I was under the impression that if a Serre fibration $f: E \rightarrow B$ has a right inverse $s: B \rightarrow E$, then the associated Serre spectral sequence would collapse on the second page. This seems to be [wrong](https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0166864107003197/1-s2.0-S0166864107003197-main.pdf?_tid=20ce72ea-5601-4862-ad6c-7e6ed2798e6a&acdnat=1530169458_b0aa8cefea74ae3a92bbbd02a1f1dafc) in general. Is there an additional mild condition on $f$ that would rectify this, or is this just a wrong way to think about the situation?

Comment: second page of what book?

Comment: If $f$ is principal then I  believe the collapse result should hold.

Comment: @mathworker21 I mean the $E_2$ page of the (co)homology Serre spectral sequence.

Comment: @Tyrone Sure, because then the bundle is a product bundle. Probably the desired statement in general has something to do with Leray-Hirsch. I believe a calculation of the transgression shows the spectral sequence also collapses for sphere bundles admitting a section.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I recently needed to know this, so I thought I would share my understanding. Ultimately, I believe that you just need field coefficients. I've sketched an argument below (where I assume there is no twisting of coefficients).

**Claim.**
Suppose $F \overset{i}\to E \overset{p}\to B$ is fibration, with $B$ and $F$ of finite type, $\pi_1(B)$ acting trivially on $\pi_*(F)$ and $\pi_0(F)=0$. Further let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field of coefficients. If the fibration $p$ admits a section $s \colon B \to E$, then
$$H^*(E;\mathbb{K}) \cong H^*(B;\mathbb{K}) \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} H^*(F;\mathbb{K}).$$

*Proof.* Consider the Leray-Serre cohomological spectral sequence
$$E_2^{p,q} = H^p(B;H^q(F;\mathbb{K})) \implies H^*(E;\mathbb{K})$$
of the fibration $F \overset{i}\to E \overset{p}\to B$. We know that
$$E_2^{p,q} = H^q(B;\mathbb{K}) \otimes_{\mathbb{K}}H^q(F;\mathbb{K})$$
since we are working with field coefficients.

In order to prove the theorem, if suffices to show that $E_2 = \dots = E_{\infty}$, i.e. that all differentials $d_2, d_3, \dots$ vanish. Indeed, since we take field coefficients, all extension problems encountered in passing from $E_\infty$ to $H^*(E;\mathbb{K})$ are trivial. In other words, we know that
$$H^n(E;\mathbb{K}) \cong \bigoplus E_{\infty}^{p,q}.$$
Moreover, since the fibration $p$ admits a section, it follows from the long exact sequence in cohomology (induced by $p$) that
$$
i^* \colon H^q(E;\mathbb{K}) \to H^q(F;\mathbb{K})
$$
is surjective for all $q$. But recall that $i^*$ is equal to the composition
$$H^q(E;\mathbb{K}) \twoheadrightarrow E_{\infty}^{0,q} = E_{q+1}^{0,q} \subseteq E_q^{0,q} \subseteq \dots \subseteq E_2^{0,q} = H^q(F;\mathbb{K}).$$
So the surjectivity of $i^*$ forces the above inclusions to be equalities. Thus all $d_r$, when restricted to the $q$-axis, must vanish.

On the other hand, we know that
$$E_2^{p,q} = E_2^{p,0} \otimes E_2^{0,q}$$
since $\mathbb{K}$ is a field and $d_2=0$ on $E_2^{p,0}$ (as a first quadrant spectral sequence). Moreover, $d_2$ is a derivation with respect to this tensor product decomposition of the $E_2$-page, thus all $d_2$ differentials vanish and $E_3 = E_2$.

We can repeat the above argument for $d_3$ differentials and, continuing in this fashion, we see that the spectral sequence collapses at $E_2$, as desired. QED

Comment: Hi Baylee! I haven't checked your argument carefully, but I think the papers "Fiber bundles with cross sections and noncollapsing spectral sequences" by Gottlieb and "On the Characteristic Zero Cohomology of the Free Loop Space" by Smith have examples with nonzero differentials on field coefficients and simply connected base.

Comment: Hi @Cihan! Ah, thank you! I didn't know about this; I must be going wrong somewhere then.